# Adding functions to a webpage where visibility is restricted by your domain login/role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

i am currently working on a small, simple project. I have a list of users stored in a database like so:
Id (uniqueidentifier primary key), FirstName(varchar), LastName(varchar), PhoneNo(varchar), DomainAC(varchar)

I am displaying their information on a webpage like so :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<WhoIs.Models.Employee>>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNo) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DomainAC) %>
            </th>
            <th>
                <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Branch) %>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNo) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DomainAC) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Branch) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <% if (User.IsInRole(@"Admin") || User.Identity.Name == item.DomainAC) {%>
                    <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) %> |
                    <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id }) %>
                <% } %>
            </td>

        </tr>
    <% } %>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This works OK, it throws up a little webpage of users and has 3 pointless links displayed alongside them - but I'm not sure where to go from here - how do I make these links work as simply/effectively as possible ?

The functionality I would like is simply

```
if(DomainAC == currently logged in Domain AC || currently logged in Domain AC is admin)
    Allow user to edit/update details.
else 
{
user is normal, no buttons/actions - just display the list.
}
```

Can anyone explain to me simply what I need to do to make this work please ? I posted a question similar to this before, and it has really went over my head - talk of ActionControllers etc, with no explanation of where they go in your project/how they all link together/how they are used.

Can anyone help me with this please? I will be putting a small bounty on this in two days and awarding it to the best answer as this is something that's cropped up a lot for me lately! Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to know how to create an edit page? I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: @kyle I want to know how to give a user the ability to edit their "profile" (my table) but only if they are logged into their Windows domain account.

Comment: Seems like you have correctly set the *edit* and *delete* links not to show unless the user is admin or looking at their own info. I suspect you want to extend similar control to your action method. If so, please add your action method for edit and delete to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer isnt horribly complicated, just depends on how you want to implement it.  (I am assuming you're using MVC due to how some of this is implemented and to how you have this tagged)

In the controller you would need to determine if the user is logged in and that data.  Ok, lets say you have that

```
 public ActionResult LoadUserData(){
     var model = new LoadUserDataModel();

     // code here to populate your model

     var isUserAuthenticated = MethodToFigureOutIfUserIsAuthenticated(); // returns bool

     ViewBag.isUserAuthenticated = isUserAuthenticated; // I don't like using the ViewBag so you can add this to the model if you wish.

     return View(model);
 }
```

Not gonna lie, to those experts out there looking at this they might be freaking out a bit.  I understand.  A method attribute would be far more effective but I'm trying to help the fellow out here.

ok now on the view (I just copied yours and made a few tweaks)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<WhoIs.Models.Employee>>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<% if (ViewBag.isUserAuthenticated) {%>
<p>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
</p>
<% } %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNo) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DomainAC) %>
        </th>
        <th>
            <%: Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Branch) %>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNo) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DomainAC) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Branch) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <% if (ViewBag.isUserAuthenticated) {%>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) %> |
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id }) %>
            <% } %>
        </td>

    </tr>
<% } %>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and that ... should work for you.

So back to another part of your question.  You wanted to know how all of this ties together.  That answer is very not easy to answer in a simple question answer forum.  So... I will give a brief overview of what the roles are.

MVC stands for model/view/controller.  Its a methodology of programming that separates concerns of application development.  Basically a Controller is the data/getter/grabber/saver of the application.  There is a whole level of understanding about business application development that can't be explained in less than 4 years at a major university, but lets just say that is the meat and potatoes of your application.  The View is the presentation of the Application.  Also known as the User Interface.  The portion controls the applications user input and actual actions of the application.  The Model is the glue that ties them together.  The controller will grab the data needed to fill the model, and then pass the model to the view, and the view will then consume it.

Why is this necessary?  Its not just necessary, its absolutely required if you want to develop applications that are maintainable and code that reusable.  But thats also the beauty of MVC.

I hope this answered your question.  If you need more clarification then let me know and I will update my answer accordingly.

I also suggest you go to this website http://www.asp.net/mvc and look to the right, you will see a section that says Pluralsight and a web series on MVC4.  I found that most helpful when I was getting started with MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the User Role Privilege in the controller itself, based on that you can redirect the response to the web page.

you make have two page to list all the users and another one page with create button. In the controller based on the user role you can redirect the responses to the relevant page.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled by two ways.

1. Take a bool type property in model for ex: IsUserAuthenticated and set it's value from controller i.e. True or false. Now when you come in view, put if-else block for checking that if user is authenticated or not. If value is true, than show Edit/Delete button.
2. You can use ViewBag for this. Create a dynamic property in controller ex: ViewBag.IsUserAuthenticated and set it's value True or false. Now put if-else block in view.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, most extensible and maintainable way to to do this is to use an Extension Method on [IPrincipal Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal%28v=vs.99%29.aspx).

However it appears you have conflicting information in your question as

> if (User.IsInRole(@"Admin") || User.Identity.Name == item.DomainAC)

does not seem to be the same logic as

> if(DomainAC == currently logged in Domain AC || currently logged in Domain AC is admin)

So I'm not sure this code is what you want.

The WebViewPage has access to the currently logged in user via [WebPageRenderingBase.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.user%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) as an `IPrincipal`.

```
namespace MyProject.<whatever>
{
  public static IPrincipalExtensions
  {
    public bool IsAdminOrDomainAC(this IPrincipal instance, string name)
    {
      if (instance == null
        || instance.Identity == null
        || !instance.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
        return false;
      }

      return instance.IsInRole(@"Admin")
        || instance.Identity.Name == name;
    }
  }
}
```

Now your view code looks like:

```
 <td>
   <% if this.User.IsAdminOrDomainAc(item.DomainAC) {%>
     <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) %> |
     <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id }) %>
   <% } %>
 </td>
```

You can even edit the web.config file in the **Views** directory and add

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="MyProject.<whatever>" />
```

To make the extension method available to all views in the views folder without using the `using MyProject.<whatever>` at the top of every view.

This assumes that you are returning multiple records and the user only has access to edit/delete some of them.  You also need to make sure that in your Edit/Delete methods that the item loaded the user has access to.  Because it's an extension method on IPrincipal it can be used in the controller as well, leaving you with a single, maintainable location for logic.

```
using MyProject.<whatever>

public class MyController
{
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
  {
    var item= DB.GetRow(id) //whatever that looks like    

    if (!this.User.IsAdminOrDomainAc(item.DomainAC))
    {
      return this.RedirecToAction("Index");
    }

    return this.View(item);
  }
```